# odoo Qweb report lines in alphabetical order

Tags: xml, report, sql-order-by, odoo, qweb

I'm getting crazy for what I believe it is a really silly matter.
I need to render the result of an array in alphabetical order:

```
 <tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="l"> 
                    <td>
                       <span t-field="l.name"/>
                    </td>
```

should I use a SQL query `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY`l.name`DESC`?
but it seams too complicated, I have the feeling there is a simple condition to render it correctly...

any help highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/qweb-order-array-before-iterating-with-foreach-90733)

You could set a new variable to *order_line.sorted()* and then iterate on the new variable

For sorting have a look at [Odoo reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.sorted)

Comment: Thanks Alessandro,
can you tell me also where I should put it....
            <t t-esc="o.order_line.sort()"/>
                    <tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="l">
give me the error : "'sale.order.line' object has no attribute 'sort'" while evaluating 'o.order_line.sort()'" while evaluating

Answer (score 2):

I have just faced this problem and I was able to solve it with `sorted` function, as @Alessandro Ruffolo wrote. You have to pass the right parameters to that function, in your case it would be:

```
<tr t-foreach="o.order_line.sorted(key=lambda r: r.name, reverse=True)" t-as="l"> 
    <td>
        <span t-field="l.name"/>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot use ".sort()" for one main reason:

- ".sort()" on a list sorts the list in place, returning `None`

The best you can do is to use `sorted`, which does not modify the iterable you pass to it but returns its sorted value. Like this:

```
 <tr t-foreach="sorted(o.order_line, key=lambda x: x.get('A_FIELD_TO_SORT_UPON')" t-as="l">
```

The `key` could be any fuction that returns the value to be used for sorting.

See some more examples on `sorted` usage [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort item in Odoo Report this is will work!!!

```
<tr t-foreach="get_room_used_detail(data['form']['date_start'],data['form']['date_end']).sorted(key=lambda x: x.checkin)" t-as="info">
```