# Odoo Reports : How Can i sort My Report

Tags: odoo-10

i need to sort my report ascending or descending
according to "a.sales_count"

```xml
<tr t-foreach="percent" t-as="a">
    <t></t>
     <td style="white-space: text-nowrap;">
        <span t-esc="a.name"/>
     </td>
     <td style="white-space: text-nowrap;">
     <t t-if="a.sales_count == 0">
         <strong>There are no sold kind in stock</strong>
     </t>
        <t t-elif="a.sales_count &gt; 0">
          <span t-esc="a.sales_count"/>
         </t>
     </td>
     <td style="white-space: text-nowrap;">
         <span t-esc="a.purchase_count"/>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474335/odoo-qweb-report-lines-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: gives me an error "list has no attribute sorted"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```xml
<tr t-foreach="sorted(percent, key= lambda x:x.get('sales_count')" t-as="a">                              
     <td style="white-space: text-nowrap;">
          <span t-esc="a.name"/>
     </td>
      <td style="white-space: text-nowrap;">
         <t t-if="a.sales_count == 0">
           <strong>There are no sold kind in stock</strong>
         </t>
        <t t-elif="a.sales_count &gt; 0">
             <span t-esc="a.sales_count"/>
         </t>
          </td>
              <td style="white-space: text-nowrap;">
                 <span t-esc="a.purchase_count"/>
          </td>
```

Hope this will help you